# Am I legally required to do something about the toll booth violations letters that I receive for the previous resident?

Tags: united-states

The person who lived in my apartment before I is getting a lot of toll booth violations. In the 15 months, I have lived in this apartment, they have received at least 10 to 15 letters. Both husband and wife.

I have been returning these mails back to USPS. Am I legally required to do anything more in this situation?

I live in New Jersey

Comment: I have notified the building management about this. They said, they will try to contact that person.

Comment: "I have notified the building management about this. They said, they will try to contact that person": you've already done more than you have to.  All you are required to do is to return the letters to USPS, as you've done.  It might be a courtesy to the other person to let them know about it to minimize late fees or penalties, but you are under no obligation to do so.